# Attribution alignment and order should be consistent with the website

Tags: feature-request, design, ios-app

The new attribution style on posts looks great, and brings some consistency with the website which is good. This is how it looks on an iPhone (in landscape, to emphasise the alignment; in portrait both boxes take up the whole screen width):

> [image]

This is how it looks on the website:

> [image]

Notice the switched order? That's confusing. Since the app version is aligned left it does make more sense in the order that it is, but since the website version is right aligned and the idea here is obviously consistency with the website could we switch the alignment and order to match?